# Redirect from domainA.example.com and domainB.example.com to domainC.example.com/test

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domains:

**domainA.example.com,
domainB.example.com**

And they need to be redirected to: **domainC.example.com/test**

The CNAME is already changed so if i go to domainA.example.com i go to domainC.example.com but it needs to point to the subfolder test.

i've read that you can do that with .htaccess but in which .htaccess file do i have to put the RewriteCond? is it in the domainC.example.com directory or in the subfolder?

I've never used the RewriteCond so if somebody could show me something that should do the trick it would really come in handy.

thx.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is for programming questions, not hardware or general computer advice. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. There are other [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)  sites that are more appropriate for this type of question. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that via `mod_rewrite` rules in `.htaccess`.

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domainA| domainB)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domainC.example.com/test%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: thx! 

.htaccess:

# BEGIN rewrite
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domainA|domainB)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domainC.example.com/test%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
# END rewrite

made it work! thx

Comment: Btw is it possible to make to keep the url-name? I mean if we host a url for example:

www.domainA.org

but it needs to point to www.domainB.example.com/subfolder. I know how to redirect it but can i still use www.domainA.org to show as url and not the path to the subfolder?

Comment: That is usually not possible but if you can enable `mod_proxy` on `www.domainA.org` then it can be possible.